# Using StringBuilder to build a string out of extracted chars

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble understanding why the string I'm trying to build out of this for-loop is only returning one character. I have a 4 character string that I iterate through for all the chars that match '0', but the logic only occurs once throughout. What am I missing?

```
private void updateDurationColor(SpinClassMovement movement){

        String duration = (String) TextFormatUtil.getFormattedTimeInMinutesAndSeconds(movement.getMovementLengthInMinutes() + movement.getMovementLengthInSeconds());

        for(int i = 0; i < duration.length(); i++){

            if (duration.charAt(i) == '0'){

                Character zero = duration.charAt(i);
                StringBuilder colorDuration = new StringBuilder(zero);
                colorDuration.append(zero);

                setColor(mTimeRemaining,duration,colorDuration,Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your are initializing "colorDuration" inside the loop. Try this.

```
private void updateDurationColor(SpinClassMovement movement){

        String duration = (String) TextFormatUtil.getFormattedTimeInMinutesAndSeconds(movement.getMovementLengthInMinutes() + movement.getMovementLengthInSeconds());
        StringBuilder colorDuration = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < duration.length(); i++){

            if (duration.charAt(i) == '0'){

                Character zero = duration.charAt(i);
                colorDuration.append(zero);

                setColor(mTimeRemaining,duration,colorDuration,Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, totally overlooked that! Thanks!